# SQL-ex.ru Execise 14

Tags: sql

I am trying to solve Exercise 14.on  http://www.sql-ex.ru/. The query asks for :

> Find out makers who produce only the models of the same type, and the
>   number of those models exceeds 1. Deduce: maker, type

The database schema is as follows:

```
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
Printer(code, model, color, type, price)
```

I wrote the following query;

```
select distinct maker, type
from product
where maker in (
select product.maker
from product, ( select model, code
        from printer
        union
        select model, code
        from pc
        union
        select model, code
        from laptop
           ) as T
where product.model = T.model
group by product.maker
having count(T.code) > 1 and count(distinct product.type) = 1
)
```

This is not the correct answer. What am i missing here ?

Comment: Lately more and more questions are asked about those examples on sql-ex.ru I have to mention, that the database design is really retarded and you most probably won't find it anywhere in a production environment unless the database designer has no clue. That said, it might be a good idea to look for other tutorial sites.

Comment: @fancyPants can you suggest some other site where i can practice sql against an actual database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query...

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker, type 
FROM product 
WHERE maker IN 
   (SELECT DISTINCT maker 
    FROM product 
    GROUP BY maker HAVING COUNT(distinct type) = 1
    AND count(model) > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 2):

Claudiu Haidu answer is correct, though there's an even shorter answer:

```
SELECT maker,MIN(type) 
FROM product 
GROUP BY maker 
HAVING COUNT(distinct type) = 1 AND COUNT(model) >  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it easiest possible using `max(type)` in `select`.

```
select maker, max(type)
from product
group by maker, type
having count(distinct type)=1 and count(model)>1
```

which is working without `where`, used `max`, but it was max of 1 result, you can use min with same effect

Answer (score 0):

```
select PC.Model,PC.speed,PC.hd 
from PC 
inner join Product ON Product.model = pc.model
where (pc.price < 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and this code works:

```
Select maker, type
from Product
group by maker
having count(distinct type) =1
and count(distinct model) > 1
```